# Terminology: perpendicular of cross-section

Tags: time-series, terminology

If I have a table containing time-series, I understand **cross-section** functions.

*What is the correct terminology for the category of functions that are act perpendicular to those cross-section functions?*

A rolling window function or auto-regression function along a time-series would be examples.

For lack of a better term, I've been calling them **vertical functions**, but I'd like to know the proper statistical terminology.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "longitudinal"?  It depends on what, precisely, you might mean by "perpendicular to."